# Bought a domain on AWS route 53 and the domain is registered to someone else

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I bought a domain using Route 53 on AWS. And after successfully obtaining it, it's still registered to another person/company. Does it take time for DNS to update the domain? I tried to obtain a certificate through ACM since it's needed in order to create a Cloud Distribution in CloudFront. I noticed this problem after using WHOIS and also when I never received the email to validate I was the owner of the domain after using ACM.

I registered the domain 45 mins ago.

So I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: What does Route 53 show you? Does it say that you have successfully bought the domain? DNS propagation follows eventual consistency and can take up to 48 hours to show the effect. Also, email validation is not the preferred way for domain validation, instead it is recommended to do it via record editing. And since you have done it only 45 min ago, give it some time and it should show the effect.

Comment: Sweet, yeah I figured it was the DNS propagation. Route 53 says the domain was purchased. Ok, I'll wait patiently.

Comment: Great! Added as an answer then. You can accept it once it is confirmed for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS propagation can take up to 48 hours to reflect. You need to wait for it to reflect.

Comment: You might want to re-read the question.  The claim is made that a domain was registered ("bought") and yet is (still) in use by someone else, which is impossible.  48 hours is a theoretical maximum for authoritative name server changes to become globally visible, rarely if ever observed in the wild, and certainly not applicable to the scenario described.

Comment: Hmm, now thinking again I think you are right. Authoritative Name Servers should not take up this much time in update. Stub resolvers and recursive resolvers usually notice more latency.

@JD333 how does the DNS looks now? Is the issue resolved?